# Pedir números e indicar al usuario cuáles de ellos son múltiplo de 3

Tags: c++, bucle-for, bucles, while

Realice un programa en C++ con las siguientes características:

- Pedir al usuario valores enteros hasta que ingrese el valor 0 (cero).
- Ir mostrando por pantalla numero de orden, valor ingresado y, de ser necesario, si es múltiplo de 3. (ver formato en el ejemplo)
- Al finalizar la carga, mostrar la cantidad de múltiplos de 3 ingresados.

El código:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int valores_enteros, multiplos_de_3;
    int valor = valores_enteros;
    
    multiplos_de_3 = 0;
    
    cin >> valores_enteros;
        
    while(valores_enteros!=0);
    {
        if(valores_enteros%3==0)
        {
            cout << valor << ";" << " multiplo de 3";
        }
        
        else
        {
            cout << valor;
        }
        cout << endl;
        
        valor++;

    
    }

    return 0;   
 }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Y cual es el problema?

Comment: Tu `while` jamas terminara ya que nunca alteras el valor de
`valores_enteros` dentro de la misma. Ademas, a `valor` le
das el valor inicial de `valores_enteros`, pero a
`valores_enteros` no le das ningun valor inicial, asi que el
valor inicial de `valor` sera basura cuando lo imprimas (O
probablemente sea `0` si estas con un build de debug).

Answer (score 1):

Primero, cuando quieras ingresar tantos números como quieras hasta introducir un valor especifico, debes usar la instrucción `do-while`, la cual te permite ejecutar una parte del código de manera repetitiva hasta que se cumpla la condición que dices, en tu caso hasta que el número ingresado sea 0.
Por otro lado, intenta trabajar con el menor número de variables posibles e inicializarlas siempre a un valor conocido, así evitarás que tu código se ejecute de manera impredecible.

El código que buscas se puede parecer algo a lo siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int valores_enteros = 0, multiplos_de_3 = 0;
    int orden = 0;

    do
    {
        cout << "Inserte un valor (0 para salir): ";
        cin >> valores_enteros;
        cout << "Numero ingresado: " << valores_enteros << endl;
    
        orden = valores_enteros%3;
        if(orden == 0)
        {
            cout << "El numero " << valores_enteros << " es multiplo de 3" << endl << endl;
            multiplos_de_3++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "El numero " << valores_enteros << " NO es multiplo de 3. Su orden es: " << orden << endl << endl;
        }
    } while (valores_enteros != 0);

    cout << "Cantidad de multiplos de 3: " << multiplos_de_3;

    return 0;   
 }
```

De este modo, permites al usuario que inserte tantos números como quiera (hasta que se introduzca un 0). Se va mostrando el orden del número en caso de no ser múltiplo de 3, y si es múltiplo de 3 se indicará por pantalla. Finalmente, cuando introduzcas un 0, se mostrará por pantalla el total de número múltiplos de 3 que has introducido.
Este código también funciona para número negativos. En caso de que sólo quieras que se introduzcan números positivos tendrás que valorar la posibilidad de comprobar mediante un `if` el valor del número introducido y ejecutar el código sólo cuando `valores_enteros` sea mayor que 0.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Primero que todo. Tu ciclo while debes cambiarlo por un for o por uno do while porque con la estrcutura del ciclo while, no podras preguntar por primera vez y seguir iterando infinitamente dentro del ciclo while para saber si el numero es distinto a 0 o no. En la práctica, pudedes poner una variable fuera y otra dentro para preguntar por los valores pero no tendria sentido. Mejor lo haces una sola vez con otra estructura repetitiva y ya. Otra cosa, como te comentan anteriormente, tu ciclo nunca terminará debido a que la variable valores_enteros que es la que te permite la salida del ciclo, nunca se modifica a 0 y por tanto, no se va a salir nunca del ciclo while.
Aqui te envio el código modificado ligeramente:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int valores;      // estos son los numeros que iran apareciendo en pantalla
    int multiplos_de_3 = 0;       // cantidad de multiplos de 3
    int i = 0;          // esto es para mostrar los valores en forma de lista numerica    
            
    // se detiene cuando el usuario entra un valor igual a 0
    do
    {
        // se le pide al usuario que introduzca un valor numerico
        cout << "Introduzca un numero;" 
        cin >> valores; // se guardan los valores en la variable

        // si el valor es multiplo de 3 y no es igual a 0 (algunas personas dicen que 0 no es multipl0 de ningun numero)   :)
        if(valores%3==0 && valores!=0)
        {
            // se ordena numericamente la salida de los datos, 
           // se muestran los valores y ademas se muestra el mensaje: multiplo de 3
            cout << i << "-" << valores << " multiplo de 3";     
                        
            // se cuenta la cantidad de multiplos de 3
            multiplos_de_3 ++;
        }
        
        // si no es multiplo de 3 entonces:
        else
        {
            // se muestra los valores y el orden numerico
            cout cout << i << "-" << valores;
        }
        cout << endl; 
        
        // aqui se aumenta la variable i que es la que se encarga de mostrar los numeros en forma numerica
        i++;
    } while(valores!=0);

    // se muestran la cantidad de multiplos de 3
    cout << "Cantidad de multiplos de 3: " << multiplos_de_3;

    return 0;   
}
```